# Allow access to REST API only for mobile devices

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, spring-mobile

It is possible to allow only mobile devices to access REST API on my server side `(Based on spring framework)` ?

Comment: No it's not possible. Please visit this link :  http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219028/how-to-safeguard-a-rest-api-for-only-trusted-mobile-applications.

Comment: @Bhavin it was 3 years ago, maybe something changed ( :

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, don't say that is the best way but anyway it works. For that I'm using [spring-mobile library](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mobile)

Create a new Interceptor, to check device type and know to allow him to access API or not, code:

```
public class MobileDeviceInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        Device d = new LiteDeviceResolver().resolveDevice(request);
        if(!d.isNormal()) {
            return true;
        }
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        return false;
    }
}
```

In configuration class add it:

```
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    ...

    @Bean
    public MobileDeviceInterceptor deviceTypeInterceptor(){
        return new MobileDeviceInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(deviceTypeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Test it right now and it works.

**Note** You have to know if `User-Agent` headers was changed on non mobile platform into mobile values for example:

- android
- ipad
- silk
- ...

This interceptor will allow access.